# Surjective function - error in course notes?

Tags: functions

[image: Exersise 1]
The question is to define f as the mapping from $a\to b$ and g as the mapping $b \to a$, and dertimine if either is a function and if they are if they are surjective or injective or both. This is just an exersise so the answer is given - but the answer says that g is not surjective because $im(g)=\{0,1,2,\}\subset\{0,1,2,3\}$. The textbook definition of surjective says: "The function f is said to be surjective if the range of f equals the set B; that is, for each $y ∈ B$ there exists some $x ∈ A$ such that $f(x) = y$, which I believe has been satisfied? And according to every other definition of surjective I can find, g would be surjective. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing this I noticed something in the formulation of the question which made me realise why it wasn't surjective.

It says in the text: "We are looking at functions with where the domain is a subset of $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and co-domain $\{0,1,2,3\}$" so column $a$ is not the co-domain of g - and thus there is a $3$ that isn't mapped from $b$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).